# Given a positive integer array, find starting indexes of contiguous subsequences of length L that their sum equals to S

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Given a positive integer array whose values are in [1, 8], I want to find the starting indexes of contiguous subsequences of length L, which their sum is equal to S. This query can be denoted as Q< L, S >. An example is given below:

```
A: [3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 6, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3]  
Q< 3, 5 > : [5, 6, 14, 15] ;  
Starting at index 5:  {1, 3, 1},  
Starting at index 6:  {3, 1, 1},  
Starting at index 14: {3, 1, 1},  
Starting at index 15: {1, 1, 3}

Q< 4, 9 > : [0, 12] ;  
Starting at index 0:  {3, 2, 3, 1},  
Starting at index 12: {3, 2, 3, 1}
```

The result of the query can be calculated trivially in O(n) time. Is there any way of finding these indices in O(1) or O(log n) time by preprocessing the array? The space complexity of the preprocessed array's data structure preferably should not exceed O(n).

Comment: for a list of length `n` there can be at most `n` indices of length `L` and sum `S` which can be computed in `O(n)`. Ideally each element takes `O(1)` time to compute. I do not think you can do better that that.

Comment: @thebenman Well, you could precompute the results of Q< L, S > for a given A for all possible values of L and S and store them in a hash table (with L and S as key and the start indices as values). This precomputation could be done in O(n^2). Queries can then be answered in O(1). However, space complexity is also O(n^2).

Comment: @SaiBot There are an infinite possibilities that `S` can take. You cannot certainly precompute it in `O(n^2)`

Comment: @thebenman there are only n^2 possible continuous subsequences of A, so there should only be n^2 possible sums.

Comment: @SaiBot right right. got it

Comment: thebenman's first comment is the answer. An algorithm that generates O(n) results cannot run in less than O(n) time.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a summation array to find the sum of L contiguous elements in O(n) time.

```
A: [3,2,3,1,2,1,3,1]
S: [3,5,8,9,11,12,15,16]
```

Now for each element i in A, you can find its summation by S[i+L]-S[i]. Overall complexity will be O(n).

```
    int n = 9;
    int a[] = {0,3,2,3,1,2,1,3,1};
    int l = 3;
    int sum = 5;
    int s[] = new int[n];

    s[0] = a[0];
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        s[i] = a[i]+s[i-1];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n-l;i++)
    {

        int cur = s[i+l]-s[i];

        if(cur == sum)
        {
            System.out.println(cur);
        }
    }
```